# Memmap AttributeError when trying to access nifti image header

Tags: nifti, nibabel

After loading a NIFTI (.nii) image (using Nibabel) with the code `scan = nibabel.load(filepath)`, it is useful to display the image header information via `scan.header`.

If you call `scan.get_fdata()` before calling `scan.header`, the error arises: `AttributeError: 'memmap' object has no attribute 'header'`. Example of such code:

```
scan = nibabel.load(test_image.nii)
scan_volume_data = scan.get_fdata()
print(scan.header)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `scan.header` before calling `scan.get_fdata()`. This is because after calling `scan.get_fdata()`, the image object gets transformed to a memmap (memory-map) object, which loses the header information. Example of correct code is the following:

```
scan = nibabel.load(test_image.nii)
print(scan.header)
scan_volume_data = scan.get_fdata()
```

We can observe the change of the image datatype with the following code:

```
scan = nibabel.load(test_image.nii)
print(type(scan)) # <class 'numpy.memmap'>
scan_volume_data = scan.get_fdata()
print(type(scan)) # <class 'nibabel.nifti1.Nifti1Image'>
```